# How to match elements which have certain class but that are also not children of specific element?

Tags: jquery

I want to match all drop-down items that have specific class, but only if that class don't have specific parent (by class as well).

Currently I found a way to only match those drop-down items that do not have the first class:

```
$("a.dropdown-item").not(".some_class");
```

But I need to match the `not()` part for elements whose parent dropdown div doesn't have the `unique_dropdown` as well

I tried the following but that didn't work:

```
$("a.dropdown-item").not("some_class", $(this).closest(".unique_dropdown"));
```

and

```
$("a.dropdown-item").not("some_class", $("a.dropdown-item").closest(".unique_dropdown"));
```

The html:

```
<div class="dropdown unique_dropdown">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_other_class"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_other_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_other_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item some_class"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I only want to match `<a>` elements with `some_class` that are children of the `.dropdown` div without `.unique_dropdown` class

Comment: what is your html ?

Comment: I'm not sure `.not()` accepts a second parameter. Also as Dippas say, please include the relevant html so we can look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that I understood well, but I hope this does the trick

```
$(".dropdown:not(.unique_class) a.dropdown-item:not(.some_class)")
```

Comment: thank you, I added html for better clarification - does this help?

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. I tested the css selector with your HTML code. The answer I gave should still work

Comment: thank you, looks like it working, just in my case it only worked when I changed `div:not(.unique_class)` to `.dropdown:not(.unique_class)`